# how to show - ArrayList<Integer[]> lista = new ArrayList<>()

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I have small problem. I want to show all tables in my ArrayList

The code:

```
Integer[] numbers = {4, 7, 2, 1, 14, 23, 10, 5};


ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

    list.add(numbers);
    list.add(numbers);
    list.add(numbers);
    list.add(numbers);

    System.out.println(list.size());

    show(list);
```

---

```
public static <T> void show(ArrayList<Integer[]> arg){
    for (Integer[] i: arg){
        System.out.println(i.toString());

        }
```

All i see is:

```
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@60e53b93
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@60e53b93
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@60e53b93
[Ljava.lang.Integer;@60e53b93
```

Use toString to view all records?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Use `java.util.Arrays.toString(Object[] a)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your show method as below. Hope this will help you.

```
public static <T> void show(ArrayList<Integer[]> arg) {

    for (final Integer[] i : arg) {
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < i.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(j + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @NishantBhardwaz finally it works ;)

Comment: @ŁukaszSzumowski Welcome.